# Halting Reset that's in Progress

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, reset

I'm after making a moronic mistake and I can't seem to find anything online quickly, that'll allow me to resolve it.

I was given a barely used new P.C. from a friend of mine. I moved all my file old computer on to an external hard drive, and then transferred them onto the new computer. When my friend set it up, they used American settings instead of U.K ones, so I decided it might be easier to wipe the whole thing than having to keep changing the settings. I picked the nuclear option of clearing everything.

When transferring the files from the external hard drive, I thought I used Ctl C but must of used Ctl X. Is there any way of stopping this reset while it's in motion? I'm at 15% now. Also, if there is no way of stopping it, what are my options afterwards?

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

EDIT: By the nuclear option of clearing everything, I meant carrying out a P.C. reset.

Comment: Apologies too, if I don't have all the info here. I was typing in a bit of a rush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should always be a cancel option somewhere.

In this situation though I'd just let it finish, its probably the safest option and well, you do want the files there, right? You can always copy it back once its done.

After the fact, if you don't write to the drive, something like [recurva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) might be able to 'undo' the deletion of the files without needing to copy them back. For that matter you could rightclick on where the files were and select "undo move".

Comment: wait. *resetting* your PC? You're not moving stuff, you're running refresh... that's completely different - depending on what you're doing that would wipe your computer clean other than the OS. You might still be able to run recovery software on the external HDD once you're done I guess.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I was unclear. I'll give that recurva a go on the HDD now though. Thanks again.

Comment: Unclear, no completely different, yeah. Recurva or similar data recovery software's your best bet here